# Django project- adding a new user

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I need to add a new user profile to my Django project for a new employee who is starting next week- I tried doing this via www.mysite.co.uk/admin and going to Authentication & Authorisation -> Add User, I set up the username & password, and gave the user profile admin privileges. It said that the user had been created successfully, but when I tried to get hold of the user profile that I had just added in the command line, by running the following commands:

```
from employees import models

from employees.models import Employee

allEmps = Employee.objects.all()

newUser = allEmps.filter(first_name = "name")
```

`newUser` just became an empty array, so clearly the user has not been added to the database... If I run the same commands, but using my name, rather than the name of the user I've just tried adding, newUser holds an array of one element (my user account), which I can then assign to a variable in order to check its properties, etc.

I then tried creating a new user directly in the command line, so ran:

```
newEmployee = Employee(first_name = "name", surname = "surname")
```

and this seemed to create an Employee object locally

How do I actually add a new user to my Django project/ database?

My user database entry is an `Employee`- but when I look in `employees.models` at the `Employee` class, there is no 'add_employee' view...

Should I run

```
newEmployee = Employee(first_name = "name", surname = "surname")
```

from a shell on the live server? Will this make the new employee user profile accessible via the Django admin page, so that I can set their privileges, email address, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement won't create an employee in database:

```
newEmployee = Employee(first_name = "name", surname = "surname")
```

It just creates an employee object. You could save the data to database by either do:

```
newEmployee = Employee(first_name = "name", surname = "surname")
newEmployee.save()
```

Or

```
newEmployee = Employee.objects.create(first_name = "name", surname = "surname")
```

**Edit:**

I'm too fast to answer the question but ignored the other part of it. You shouldn't use production shell to add new employees, but admin interface. Django first tutorial has enough example to tell you how to [add a new model to admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin), you should always read it to know the basics of django. It has the title "Writing your first Django app" for a reason.

**ReEdit:**

Django doc also has section talking about how to [extend a `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). At the end of the section, it suggests that:

> These profile models are not special in any way - they are just Django
>   models that happen to have a one-to-one link with a user model. As
>   such, they aren’t auto created when a user is created, but a
>   [django.db.models.signals.post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) could be used to create or update
>   related models as appropriate.

So your `Employee` model will not be auto created, just check the doc and use `post_save` method.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. Presumably I would need to do this from a shell on the live server, i.e. where the live Django project/ database is?

Comment: Using the Admin interface to add the user was the first thing I tried...

Comment: `User` and `Employee` are two different models, right?

Comment: Ah- I think I've realised what my mistake was- after adding the employee via the Admin interface, I tried querying the database from my local machine- but hadn't pulled from the server before doing that, so my local database would still have been out of date. I'll try querying the live database to make sure that they are there now...

Comment: Where did you get `User` from? I don't think I've used that anywhere...? I don't need to add a new model- just want to add a new entry of the `Employee` model to the database...

Comment: **You** mentioned `User` lol. `Authentication and authorization` section is built in in django and `User` model is there by default. You created username and password for django user model, it has nothing to do with `Employee`. If you ever add `Employee` model you need to register that to admin site. For `User` documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/

Comment: Ok, I think maybe I misunderstood the problem I'm having- the user has been added, and is there- I can see them in the list of employees on the Django Admin 'Users' page... It's just that I can't actually log in to the Django app with that profile at the moment... seemingly because the profile has no projects associated with it, and I think the code expects there to be a project when the user logs in... That's something I'm going to need to fix in the code.

Comment: `Employee` is a model in the database.

Comment: I haven't mentioned `User` anywhere... do you mean the 'Add User' link on the 'Authentication & Authorisation' page in Django Admin...? I don't have any model called `User` in my database, only `Employee`

Comment: OK, dude, I don't know what else I can do to make you understand, but I've already explained in my comment, `User` is a built in model from django, I also posted a link for you to take a look. I also mentioned that `Employee` model is a new model you added, but `Add User` link only create a django `User`, not an `Employee`. And I will re-post the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/.

Comment: Apologies- I completely misunderstood what you meant there- I thought you meant I was using a `User` model I had defined somewhere... didn't realise it was a built in model from Django. So, I followed those instructions, and now have the user displayed in the Django admin page, and can also get them from the database on the server, but when I try to log into my site with their profile, I get an error that says: `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /projects/my-projects`, and complains that `User has no employee` - how would I add the 'Employee' model to the new `User`?

Comment: When I look at the user in the console, it tells me that they are an `Employee`... i.e. if I type in the variable that holds that user, `user`, the console displays output that says: `<Employee: firstName lastName>`

Comment: Cool, glad that you sorted things out. I updated my answer to reflect your concern. Again, everything basic is in the doc. It's a lot to learn but worth of it.

Comment: I'm still having trouble signing them into the site though, apparently because the `User has no employee`... even though in the console, if I run the name of the user, i.e. `user. it outputs `<Employee: firstname lastName>... how come the site doesn't think that the `user` is an `Employee`, but the console indicates that they are...?

Comment: It's not the site think `user` is an `employee`, but the user you are trying to login doesn't have `employee` relation with it. Are you sure you are checking the right user in console?

Comment: I'm fairly sure I am... unless I've accidentally created an `Employee` that is not a `User`...? How would I query the `Users` in the console? Where would I import `User` from?

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. Please refer to the doc first. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Comment: So, I did that, ran: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, then: `allUsers = User.objects.all()`, then `allDaves = allUsers.filter(first_name = "Dave"), (I know that there is only one user called Dave), then: `allDaves` to check- and output was "[<User: Dave>]", then `dave = allDaves[0]`, then ran `dave` to check- and output was: "<User: Dave>". Next I ran `dave.employee` and got the output "User has no employee.", so I ran `dave.employee = Employee(first_name = "Dave", surname = "Jones")`, and ran `dave.employee` to check- the output was "<Employee: Dave Jones>"...

Comment: So I can see that the User does have an Employee, and yet when I try to browse to: www.mysite.co.uk and log in with their user profile... I get an error page that says "User has no employee"...

Comment: Hint: did you save the `Employee` Dave?????? Look back at my answer again

Comment: Ahhhh!!! Completely forgot to do that then! My bad! Thanks for your help!